# Loop through json received from wikipedia api using .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to loop through  json received from wikipedia api using .each(), but it returns undefined on everything. What have I missed?

Here is **codepen:** https://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/pRerpb

Here is my **HTML:**

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/43f8201759.js">
</script>
<body>
  <h2 class="headertext">WIKIPEDIA  <br> VIEWER </h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10-md">
      <input class="searchRequest blink_me" id="cursor" type="text" placeholder="__"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="searchIcon col-2-md"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var icon = "<i class='fa fa-search fa-2x'></i>";
  $('#cursor').on("keydown", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("blink_me");
    var searchIcon = $(".searchIcon");
    searchIcon.empty();
    if ($(".searchRequest").val().length > 0) {
      searchIcon.append(icon);
    }
    searchIcon.on("click", function() {
      console.log("clicked!");
      var search = $(".searchRequest").val();
      var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + search + "&format=json&callback=?";
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          $("ul").empty();
          $.each(data[1], function(value, index) {
            $(".results").append("<ul><li><h3>" + data[1][index] + "</h3><p>" + data[2][index] + "<a href=\"" + data[3][index] + "\"> Read More...</a></p></li></ul>");
          });
          searchIcon.empty();
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: do you need the jsonp? Whats the format of the returned value?

Comment: If it's not a jQuery collection, why not just use ``.forEach()``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `$.each(data[1], function(value, index)` you've to switch value to index and viceversa like this `$.each(data[1], function(index, value)`

For reference: [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much aprreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through your code. Please change 
`$.each(data[1], function(value, index)` to

```
$.each(data[1], function(index, value)
```

Comment: Thank you shi! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a crude way of going about this but one way I verify that the information is what it should be is to iterate with a nested for loop.

It may not solve the immediate problem, but its a way to go to understand how this thing is working.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          {
             ///alert(data[i]); //See what data you're passing to WIKIPEDIA's API

             for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++)
             {
                 //See what data WIKIPEDIA's API is passing to you
                 //From here, you can determin which value (j) to us (e.g. j = 0 is the Title)
                 //Once you hav that, you can use it to append to you 'results' class

                 alert('i = ' + i + '| j = ' + j);
                 alert('data = ' + data[i][j]); 


                 ///////////
                 //$(".results").append("<ul><li><h3>" + data[i][j] + "</h3><p>" 
                 //+ data[i][j] + "<a href=\"" + data[i][j] 
                 //+ "\"> Read More...</a></p></li></ul>");
                 ///////////
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a fix for your problem (fixed by [Roberto Russo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575748/roberto-russo)), there is something else going on that's probably not intended: you register `searchIcon.on("click")` callback inside `$('#cursor').on("keydown")` callback. What this means is that every time `keydown` event fires on the `$(#cursor)` element, a new listener will be added to `searchIcon.on("click")`. That's why you see "clicked!" printed multiple times for just one click. Also, if you check the network log, you'll see multiple requests sent to the wiki api for the same reason.

I'd suggest moving `searchIcon.on("click")` outside `$('#cursor').on("keydown")`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap value and index to this:
$.each(data[1], function(index, value)

Make sure whenever you call $.each() function, you cannot change the order of the arguments.

Example : $.each(arryName, function(index, value)

- index = The index associates with arryName
- value = The value associates with the index